# Wy is pickle not taking into account mutable/referenced objects?

Tags: python, numpy, pickle

The following code shows that when you pickle two objects, when one is a reference of the other (is that the right word?), after you pickle and load that relationship is lost. Below, you can see that changes in `aa` also occur in `bb`. But, after pickle and testing for this same behavior, I would expect changes in `dd` to also occur in `ee`. But this is not the case. Can you please explain what is happening?

```
import numpy as np
aa=np.ones((5,3))
print 'aa',aa
bb=aa.T
aa[2,2]=3
print 'aa',aa, aa.nbytes
print 'bb', bb, bb.nbytes #bb also prints out hte affect of the change from aa. OK

import pickle
pickle.dump([aa,bb], open( "save.p", "wb" ))
with open("save.p", "rb") as f:
    dd,ee=pickle.load(f)
print 'dd',dd
print 'ee',ee
dd[1,0]=5 #shouldn't this affect ee also?

print 'dd',dd 
print 'ee',ee # is different than dd. I would have expected that they should be the same (except for the transpose).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior you expect is based the `numpy` concept of a `view`, arrays with a shared data buffer.  Pickle, which uses the `np.save` mechanism evidently is saving the arrays as copies, each with its own buffer.  `np.save` writes a header with shape, strides, dtype followed a byte copy of the data buffer.  Trying to replace that with a reference to a buffer that is still in memory, or saved in another file, or handled by another pickle step is awkward if not impossible.  Also a view does not have the information to replay its creation history.

`a.T` does not `know` it is a transpose.  It just knows it shares the data buffer with one or more arrays.  Same for `a[2::2, ...]`.

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/neps/npy-format.html

[Can cPickle save reshaped numpy object reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39804175/)

Also look at `ee.flags` and `ee.__array_interface__`, and compare with the other arrays.